# Leave as a linking verb

Tags: verbs

Is the use of leave correct in the following sentence?

> The November 1 assault on a Malian military outpost at Indelimane in the eastern Menaka region near Niger killed 49 soldiers, wounded three and **left 20 survivors**, the Malian Armed Forces (FAMa) said on Naovember 2. "Soldiers of the caliphate attacked a military base where elements of the apostate Malian army were stationed in the village of Indelimane," the IS said in a statement on its social media channels.

I think it is not correct because **leave** is a linking verb and after it an adjective should be used. Am I right?

Comment: "Leave" is not a linking verb. Why do you think it is? The usage in this example is fine and idiomatic. 20 survivors were left (remained alive) after the attack.

Comment: Had you considered that "leave" might be transitive with "20 survivors" as direct object? Note that it could be expanded into a complex-transitive clause, as in "left 20 survivors seriously wounded", where "seriously wounded" is an AdjP.

Comment: The use of "left" is correct in the quote.   I'm not sure your rule about "linking verbs" is quite right;  "linking" is more a way to use certain verbs and not a thing that each verb either "is" or "isn't".  In any case, idioms always trump grammar rules, and "left survivors" to mean "did not kill all of the people" is certainly in use.